# MariaDB TLS1.3 not working when selected manually

Tags: rust, mariadb

Hello i do not understandt the behavior of mariadb.

When i have no TLS Version selected in my.cnf it will start with the follwoing TLS version and cipher and my connection to rust is running:

```
1. TLS V1.3 Cipher: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
```

Wehn i manually activate TLS 1.3 in my.cnf file i get also, but this breaks the connection.

```
1. TLS V1.3 Cipher: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
```

I get this error message:

```
Error: Io(Tls(TlsError(Os { code: -2146893018, kind: Uncategorized, message: "The format of the received message was unexpected or incorrect." })))
```

Thats how i check which is active:

```
SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Ssl_version'
SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Ssl_cipher';
```

Am i looking to the wrong  variables to see which tls and cipher is active? What is going on that in auto TLS modus everything works with TLS 1.3 and is not working when i select TLS 1.3 expecial?